# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jsf

Подключила к проекту `persistence.xml`, выдает ошибку:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped
```

вот persistence:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="jsfProject">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>entity.models.UserProfile</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://sfmnew.amadeus.kz:54001/temp_autoparser"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="autoparser_user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="autoparser_user03022016"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

вот класс описывающий таблицу

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable{
    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id = null;

    @Column(name="body")
    private String body;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}

EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jsfProject");

        Query q=emf.createEntityManager().createQuery("select body from post");
```

Comment: Неплохо бы еще сам HQL запрос увидеть.

Comment: @enzo, EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jsfProject");
        Query q=emf.createEntityManager().createQuery("select body from post");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы пишете HQL, то обращаетесь не к таблице (это не SQL), а к сущности. По умолчанию  entity name совпадает с именем класса.

`createQuery("select p.body from UserProfile p")`